# Collecting the output messages in java

Tags: java, runtime, runtime-error, outputstream, runtimeexception

I'm trying to write a code that allows me to collect all the runtime messages printed into the output console. For example, while my app is running sometimes these exceptions pops up and I would like to collect them and print them as a string in my app. Here is a picture of what I mean.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjSQC.png)

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the console outputs to a file:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
System.setErr(out);
```

Also, you can take help of Java logging framework.

Comment: I believe setting `System#err`, via `System.setErr(...)`, would be more appropriate here.

Comment: yes you are right, for error messages it's the best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need this, But you can do like this

```
 List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElementArr = e.getStackTrace();
                for (StackTraceElement ele : stackTraceElementArr) {
            errors.add(e.getMessage()+","+ele.getClassName()+","+ ele.getMethodName()+","+ ele.getLineNumber());
                }
            }
        }
```

This will help you  store your error message details into List of Strings. You can do whatever you want with the List object. You can do more tweaks to satisfy your need